# What happens if services like DynDNS to control failovers fails? It's probably?

Tags: replication, failover, datacenter, dyndns

In the next diagram I'm trying to have a backup web page in another datacenter and a service like DynDNS that controls failovers in SERVER A to switch to SERVER B. But, what happens if DynDNS fails?

What is more probably, that DATACENTER A fails or DynDNS fails and make both unreachable? DynDNS has replicated controls in different datacenters?

[image: schema]

P.D.: I'm using DynDNS as example.

Answer (score 4):

If DynDNS (or whatever you're using for DNS service) fails, then you're toast.  The provider can mitigate the risk of failure in a variety of ways, to the point where (in theory) they should be able to provide a strong SLA with reasonable compensation for outages -- the fact that they don't is an interesting data point.

Comment: +1 - if you're paying *any* money for a DNS provider, they should be able to guarantee 5 nine's.

Comment: 5 nines *and* a strong penalty for failing to meet it.  Without the penalty, it's worthless.

Answer (score 3):

we use dnsmadeeasy, pretty reliable. But nonetheless, you can configure secondary name server as well as long as you are paying 2 providers to host your DNS.

Comment: I also use DNS Made Easy and have been since when they could claim 100% uptime. Even with their downtime about 12 months ago (which was malicious, not accidental), they still hit over their lifetime something like 99.99999%